# multidimensional array JAVASCRIPT something wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey guys I need soe help please :P

What's wrong with this code?

```
var arr = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var narr = []; // want to be like that [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]

function arange(mass) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mass[i].length; j++) {
            narr[mass[i]].push(mass[j][i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If i call the function there is a problem : "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined." Thank you.
Also [link here](https://repl.it/CITf/1)

Comment: The error is telling you what is wrong.    `narr[mass[i]]` is undefined.

Comment: `narr.push(mass[j][i]);` will give `[1,4,7,2,5,8,3,6,9]` so you'll need to think about how to create another level of array within the array to encapsulate each inner set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you could use this `ES6` one liner

```js
var arr = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ];
    
var res = arr.map((e, i) => e.map((_, j) => arr[j][i]));

document.write(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Answer (score 1):

You accidentally tried to call `push` on a value of `narr` instead on the array itself. Of course a primitive value has no `push` function defined. Your code should look like this:

```
var mass = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]];
var narr = [];

function arange(mass) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        var innerArray = [];
        for (var j = 0; j < mass[i].length; j++) {
            innerArray.push(mass[j][i]);
        }
        narr.push(innerArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: output need to be like that [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]

Answer (score 1):

Just take the right elememt to assign the value.

```js
var arr = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ];

function arange(mass) {
    var narr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < mass[i].length; j++) {
            narr[j] = narr[j] || [];
            narr[j][i] = mass[i][j];
        }
    }
    return narr;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arange(arr), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

ES6

```js
var arr = [
        [1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]
    ];

function arange(mass) {
    var narr = [];
    mass.forEach((a, i) => a.forEach((b, j) => {
        narr[j] = narr[j] || [];
        narr[j][i] = mass[i][j];
    }));
    return narr;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arange(arr), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a temporary array for storing intermediate values:

```js
var arr = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ];

var narr = []; 

function arange(mass) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mass.length; i++) {
        var t = []; // temporary array
        for (var j = 0; j < mass[i].length; j++) {
            t.push(mass[j][i]);
        }
        narr.push(t);
    }
}

arange(arr);

document.write(JSON.stringify(narr));
```